# How to close the specfic editor in the vscode programmatically?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm the developer for the vscode extension.

When the debugger activated, I opened a specific file in the right column editor to show the other related file for the current debug file using the below command.

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', vscode.Uri.file('/main.c.dbgasm'), 2);
```

Now I want to close it. But I have no idea to close the right column editor. There are some close editor commands but they do not fit my needs which shown below.

```js
workbench.action.closeActiveEditor
workbench.action.closeAllEditors
workbench.action.closeAllGroups
workbench.action.closeEditorsInGroup
workbench.action.closeOtherEditors
workbench.action.closeUnmodifiedEditors
```

Can anyone have idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `window.tabGroups.close()` method.

```js
 // the 'all' array is 0-based, so this is the second editor group
const sourceGroup = vscode.window.tabGroups.all[1];

// this would get the first tab in the second editor group
// if you don't know where in the editor group the file you want to close is
//    you can filter the tabs by label,url or path, see below
const myTab = sourceGroup.tabs[0];

await vscode.window.tabGroups.close(myTab, false);
```

To filter the tabs in an editor group by their path, try this:

```js
const sourceGroup = vscode.window.tabGroups.all[0]; // 'all' array is 0-based

// note small "c" to match how Uri.fsPath looks
const myPath = "c:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\Test Bed\\howdy.js";
const foundTab = sourceGroup.tabs.filter(tab => 
    (tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText) && (tab.input.uri.fsPath === myPath)
);

// close() takes an array or a single tab
if (foundTab?.length === 1) await vscode.window.tabGroups.close(foundTab, false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The path filter method is very helpful to find a specific editor to close!

Answer (score 0):

After a *lot* of reading and trial and error I came up with this solution for the similar problem I had in my extension.

```
export async function closeAnyOpenErrorFiles () {
  
  // this function will close any left over ACOMPILE.LIS or AALINKER.LIS files 
  // from the last test execution.
  for (let editor of vscode.window.visibleTextEditors) {
    if (editor.document.fileName.endsWith ("ACOMPILE.LIS") || editor.document.fileName.endsWith ("AALINKER.LIS")) {
      await vscode.window.showTextDocument(editor.document.uri, 
        { preview: false, viewColumn: editor.viewColumn, });     
      await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeActiveEditor");
    }
  }
}
```